# ScrollPane does not immediately resize ViewPort-Height if bound to a Container-Height

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-11

Consider a custom component which inherits from `VBox`. The component's height and width may change depending on some selection. In my `Scene` I usually have enough vertical space to fit the custom component but it may extend too far horizontally.

I tried placing the custom component inside a `ScrollPane` and make it grow vertically by binding the `ViewPort`'s `minHeight` to the custom component's (i.e. the `VBox`') height. Thus, preventing vertical scrollbars from appearing.

**Problem**:
In `JavaFX 8` the `ScrollPane` only resized to the correct height after another user input (e.g. a click inside the `ScrollPane` or resizing the window).

The issue is reproducible with the following code:

```java
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final VBox root = new VBox(5);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 500);

        final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(600, 300, Color.RED);
        final VBox customComponent = new VBox(rectangle);
        final ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(customComponent);
        scrollPane.minViewportHeightProperty().bind(customComponent.heightProperty());
        listView.getItems().addAll("Smaller", "Taller");
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, old, item) -> {
            if (Objects.equals(item, "Smaller")) {
                rectangle.setHeight(200);
            } else if (Objects.equals(item, "Taller")) {
                rectangle.setHeight(400);
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(listView, scrollPane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Just click on either *Smaller* or *Taller* inside the `ListView`.

The issue does not appear when adding the rectangle directly to the `ScrollPane` without the `VBox`. However, that's not a solution to my problem since I can't easily change the custom component I'm working with.
Switching to `OpenJFX 11` the `ScrollPane` correctly grows vertically, but doesn't shrink without another user input. So just upgrading my `JavaFX` version does not seem to fix the problem.

Is there a way to force the `ScrollPane` to immediately resize itself or simply another way to fit the `ScrollPane` to the custom component's height and only scroll horizontally?

Comment: Use `scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true)` instead of the binding?

Comment: This only works insofar as the resizing is now immediate, but the `ScrollPane` now won't take precedence over the `ListView` in the root-container and is still scrollable vertically.